# How can I change the expiration date of downloadable items in WooCommerce orders?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, download

I need your help because I want to change the expiration date in WooCommerce orders for downloadable items programmatically. I'm talking about this section here:

[image]

So when a customer buys a product that has downloadable items, this section appears in the order overview.

I **don't** want to change the expiration globally in each product with `$product->set_download_expiry()` - just in the order or with other words the items I receive when I execute this function on an order object:

```
$downloadable_items = $order->get_downloadable_items()
```

How can I do this? I found no function in the docs yet...

**Update**

I've already tried this out:

```
$download = new WC_Customer_Download( 'd595d561-4d37-4d6b-a19e-5ed2f5bc4ed9' );

if ( $download ) {
    $download->set_access_expires( '2022-08-22' );
    $download->save();
    error_log($download->get_access_expires());
}
```

First I've looped through the downloadable order items to get the id - then I've tried to save it that way but no success.

Comment: Currently, these field(s) become visible when an order has the status complete. Afterwards you can manually change this date via the edit order settings, which actually answers your question. I believe you want to set a date automatically though? In what way? on what basis? what requirements must this product and date meet? Can you clarify this to be able to give a _complete answer_ on your question opposite some _guidelines_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the right way:

```
$order                = wc_get_order( 157 );
$data_store           = WC_Data_Store::load( 'customer-download' );
$download_permissions = $data_store->get_downloads(
    [
        'order_id' => $order->get_id()
    ]
);

if ( $download_permissions && count( $download_permissions ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $download_permissions as $download ) {
        $download = new WC_Customer_Download( $download->get_id() );
        $download->set_access_expires( '1999-10-05' );
        $download->save();
    }
}
```

You need to get the download via the download permissions ids and not via the real download id. This is a bit strange but somehow it works. I was able to set the access expires in my order successfully.